# Sitecore Speak css and js no longer loaded

Tags: sitecore

I have a Sitecore 8 Update 2 environment.
For some reason it seems that speak css and js are no longer loaded.

for example: /sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/css/speak-default-theme.css

I'm not sure what caused this and have little knowledge about speak.
Any comments and feedback are wecome.

```
launchpad
```

[image]

```
browse media library
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see anything (errors) in the browser console?

Comment: no errors or warnings

Answer (score 0):

Faced the SAME issue when upgrading to sitecore 8.1 , the problem was this step -

The .Sitecore.Speak.Important.config file renamed to 001.Sitecore.Speak.Important.config , new pipelines have been added to it for speak 2.0 upgrade

Once I renamed file and ensured the pipelines were all there as per config fileinstructions(for 8.1 initial version) the styles came back.